# Models with optional fields with relations

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am looking for a clean way to model data that is optional, but if included will contain a reference to other data.

In example below, the cleanest relational modeling is to separate person, insurance plan, and insurance company.

```
class InsurancePlan(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="Not Indicated")
  insurancecompany = models.ForeignKey(InsuranceCompany, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
  claims_address = models.OneToOneField(UsLocation, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

class InsuranceCompany(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  some_important_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Insured(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  plan = models.ForeignKey(InsurancePlan, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and then either add a `member_id` field to the insured model or create an `Insured_Plan` table that links them.

However, what if the business requirements say that having `InsurancePlan` information is optional, because we can get by just knowing member ID and `InsuranceCompany`?

is it ok to have:

```
class Insured(models.Model):
  name=...
  plan = models.ForeignKey(InsurancePlan, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
  insurance_summary = models.ForeignKey(InsuranceCompany, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  member_id = models.CharField()
```

Im a bit rusty on relational modeling, but I think having a fk from A to B, and another from A to C where C has a fk to B as well is not good practice.

**Update**: I think the best approach is

```
class Insured(models.Model):
   name=models.CharField(max_length=20)

class InsurancePlan(models.Model):
   name=models.CharField(max_length=20, defualt="unknown/not_applicable")
   members=ManyToManyField(Insured, through='Membership')
   claims_address=models.OneToOneField(UsLocation, blank=True, null=True)
   insurance_company=models.ForeignKey(InsuranceCompany, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Membership(models.Model):
  insured=ForeignKey(Insured, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  plan=ForeignKey(InsurancePlan, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  member_id=models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

and then just make `InsurancePlan` mandatory since we can use generic blank plan as default.

Comment: When you say "because we can get by just knowing member ID and `InsuranceCompany`", where would that information be stored if not in a fk reference in the `Insured`?

Comment: it would. I was just wondering if its bad practice for when you do have `InsurancePlan` info and `InsuranceCompany` info. You end up using the fk query to `InsuranceCompany` twice

Comment: Yeah you want to avoid doing that. I'm wondering though how you would be able to infer the `InsurancePlan` using only the `InsuranceCompany` and `Insured`?

Comment: Could I do it with a conditional expression to only read `InsuranceCompany` if `InsurancePlan` is null?

Comment: Yeah that is one route. But I think there might be a better way if you explain a bit more about how you can infer the `InsurancePlan` for person using only `InsuranceCompany` and `Insured`

Comment: Its tough because you really cannot infer. we need to be able to save `InsuranceCompany` when plan is unknown or sometimes not even applicable.